# Spark AR dynamic text

Tags: instagram, spark-ar-studio

I want the script to extract the dynamic text (short date) from instagram and give text output of 36 when DDMMYY output is 050222 and 37 when DDMMYY output is 060222
The script can give me the output of short date, just that now I have to link it such that when the output is 0502222. it gives another output of 36

I have linked the script below

New here so don't know much about how to post so please bear with me

[script that needs help](https://github.com/nikolvs/sparkar-dateformat/blob/main/dateformat.js)

Comment: can you be more specific about what part of the script you're having trouble with? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.